# Prove that This Property Does Not Hold for Any Other Pair of Digits.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Given a positive integer $n,$ prove that there is a positive integer $m$
that to base ten contains only the digits $0$ and $1$ such that $n|m.$ Prove that the same holds for digits $0$ and $2,$ or $0$ and $3,$ $\cdots,$ or $0$ and $9,$ but for no other pair of digits.

I tried solving it as follows:

We consider $n$ numbers $1,11,111,\cdots,\underbrace{ 111\cdots 1}_{\text{n 
1's}}.$ We assume, neither of these numbers leave a remainder of $0$ when divided by $n.$ For if, there were such  a number in the above list, we are done. So, the possible remainders on division by $n$ are $1,2,\cdots,n-1.$ So, we have, $n$ numbers and $n-1$ remainders. By PHP, there exists two numbers that leave the same remainder on dividing by $n.$ We call these two numbers in particular as $p=\frac{10^p-1}{9}$ and $q=\frac{10^q-1}{9}.$ Then, WLOG, let $p\gt q$ and we have, $m=\frac{10^p-10^q}{9}\equiv 0\pmod n$ and $m$ is in fact the required type of number.

Similarly, for a digit $2\leq i\leq 9$ we can proceed similarly by consider the list : $$i,ii,iii,\cdots, \underbrace {iii\cdots i}_{\text{n times}},$$ and then proceeding similarly as above.

---

But then, I don't know how to show, that this is not true "for no other pair of digits."

It seems they want us to show that, if $(a,b)$ is any other digit, $n$ won't divide it! This seems a little weird and difficult to show.

Comment: Regarding the last part, i.e., "for no other pair of digits", note that would mean not including $0$. However, consider then if, for example, $n=10$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I have thought many examples, $n=17$ but then, is this meant?

Comment: @ThomasFinley I'm sorry, but your comment's meaning is not clear to me. Note that the question requires that, for *all* integers $n$, you are supposed to prove there exists an integer $m$ such that $n\mid m$ and $m$ uses only the digits $a$ and $b$ when written in base $10$. I'm stating that the digit $0$ *must* be one of the ones allowed due to cases like $n = 10$ since all integral multiples of $10$ have, in base $10$, a final digit of $0$. It's immaterial whether or not it'll work for just some examples, or even most examples, such as your $n = 17$. I hope this is clear.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Ok, I regret for the miscommunication. Let me try again. In my question it was written that, $n$ is an *arbitrary* number and this $n$ divides a number $m,$ which in turn consists only the digits $0,1$ or $0,2$ and so on. I think I have successfully proved this. But now for the next part, they phrased, "Prove $n\nmid m$ when $m$ is made up of any other pair of digits". Now, my question is, how to prove this? Now, if $n=10$ it does not divide any number $m$ which is made up of only $2$ or $3$ ? Will this suffice as the answer? (This is specifically my question)

Comment: If $n=10$, then it won't divide **any** $m$ made from two digits, unless one of those digits is zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson And will this example suffice as a proof for that second part?

Comment: @ThomasFinley As far as I can tell, you have correctly answered the first part. As for the second part, your interpretation of "Prove $n\nmid m$ when $m$ is made up of any other pair of digits" is somewhat inaccurate. It should instead be phrased something like "Prove there's at least one $n$ where $n\nmid m$ when $m$ is made up of any other pair of digits". As for how to prove this, I've already given a fairly detailed explanation in my earlier comment. Also, as for it being "sufficient", I believe it should be, but that would be up to whoever is reading your answer to determine.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Hmm...I understand. But the phrasing is admittedly ambiguous. It was a question from Niven, Zuckerman and Montgomery 's book on Number theory!

Comment: @JohnOmielan If you consider writing your comment as an answer, I 'll be more than glad to accept it!

Comment: @Prem, I'm looking at the book (exercise 50 on page 59), and that **is** the exact wording. (And, it's not ambiguous.)

Comment: Let's write $P_{a,b}(m)$ for the statement, $m$ contains only the digits $a$ and $b$. The problem is, For all $n$, for all $a$, there exists $m$ such that $P_{0,a}(m)$ and $n$ divides $m$. Show that, if $ab\ne0$, then it is not true that for all $n$ there exists $m$ such that $P_{a,b}(m)$ and $n$ divides $m$. To do the second part, all you need is a single value of $n$ for which there is no such $m$. And $n=10$ is such an $n$.

Comment: Thanks for checking that , I though the Book would have Different wording , @GerryMyerson , though I think it is ambiguous or wrong. Eg it says "given Positive Integer n [ I will take n=223 ] , show that 1 & 0 is enough" (which is true) & then it says no other Pairs will work , but Pairs (2,3) & (4,6) & (6,9) will work eg m=446 & m=669669 ! I think it is not "given Positive n" , it is "for all n" [[ Either way , thanks for checking the text & informing me !! ]]

Comment: @Prem, "given $n$, there exists $m$" means "for every $n$, there exists $m$".

Comment: "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$". "given $n$" means "for every $n$".  @Prem

Comment: @ThomasFinley FYI, one minor point is that you wrote "... as $p=\frac{10^p-1}{9}$ and $q=\frac{10^q-1}{9}.$" Your use of $p$ and $q$ as both the left side results and as exponents is somewhat confusing. I suggest it's better to use other variables for the left side results, e.g., something like "... as $m_1=\frac{10^p-1}{9}$ and $m_2=\frac{10^q-1}{9}.$" or "... as $s=\frac{10^p-1}{9}$ and $t=\frac{10^q-1}{9}.$" instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you've correctly answered the first part of the problem.

Regarding the second part, since it's asking about using a pair of decimal digits other than $(0,1), (0,2), \ldots, (0,9)$, this means it's a pair of decimal digits where *neither* of them is $0$. However, then with the first part of "Given a positive integer $n$", if we choose something like $n = 10$, all integral multiples of it will have, in base $10$, a $0$ as the final digit. Thus, there's *no* positive integer $m$ where $n\mid m$ and $m$ contains, in base $10$, *only* $2$ non-zero digits.

Regarding the question's phrasing, I don't consider it to be ambiguous because it requires that, regardless of which positive integer $n$ is "given", we can *always* find a corresponding $m$ meeting the stated conditions. Nonetheless, I suggest the first part could be made a bit clearer by, for example, using "Prove that, for any given positive integer $n$, there is a positive integer $m$ ..." instead, or even just by changing the "a" in "Given a positive ..." to "any".